# how to send stringed input into ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, multithreading, pipe

```
class envir {
    public void run() throws IOException {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash");
        builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
        builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = builder.start();
        System.out.println(process.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

How do I make it so that I can send a string as input for my process builder to automate a cli (eg `env python3`) also using threads?

If you need more info please ask; I am bad at wording these questions.

Comment: not sure what are you asking, but on other topic, "builder" is a fluent API so you can use it like a "stream" without calling "builder" each line.

Comment: Get a `Writer`, e.g. `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getInputStream()))`, and write into it.

Comment: How do you do it though?

Comment: builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
           .redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)
           .redirectErrorStream(true);

Comment: @AndyTurner can you please explain further

Comment: @GuySadoun how do I use it

Comment: @Laith Striegher - think about it as a sequence of function calls which happen one after rhe other exactly as you wrote, `builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)` **returns** the updated `builder` so then you call `redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE)` without end the line with `;` and so on. so it would look like that:

`builder.redirectInput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE).redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);`



I think fluent API makes code prettier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names of the streams of `Process` are confusing. What you actually want is the [*output* stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--):

> `public abstract OutputStream getOutputStream()`
>
> Returns the output stream connected to the normal input of the subprocess.

So:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Then write to it:

```
bw.write("Your string");
bw.newLine();
```

Comment: The important misconception that this answer corrects is this: getInputStream() creates an InputStream that you use to read the standard output of the subprocess. getOutputStream writes to the process stdin. Think: out of the subprocess INTO the parent process and into the subprocess OUT OF the parent process.

Comment: @kutschkem or, if you can't remember, read the doc :)

Comment: doesn't seem to execute command

Comment: @LaithStriegher The newLine is important, do you have that too?

Comment: Or `bw.flush()`, alternatively/additionally.

Comment: yes I did add that it isn't running the command yet

Comment: O wait Bw.flush() did work

Comment: How do I also get the output of a command as a string?

Comment: @LaithStriegher if you wrote to the input with `process.getOutputStream()`, how do you think you might get the output?

Comment: `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
`